# Strange line in Altium PCB

Tags: pcb, altium

I have an infinite long yellow line that is seen in every layer (does not belong to any layer probably). In 3d mode it is invisible.

[image]

I cannot select that object and I don't know how to delete this. Do you know how to get rid of it?

Comment: Can it be "guide"? Go Tools/Grid Manager. There's should be all those guides. Maybe one of them it is.

Comment: In Altium, there is no "grid manager". If you mean grid properties, there isn't option that could help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Guide Line or Work Guide. You can add them via the menu: Place -> Work Guide.

But, for some reasons there is no option in any menu to make changes to existing guide lines. To do that you need to open the Properties panel of the PCB (while nothing is selected), and scroll down to the "Guide Manager".

Comment: Thank you, it works :D